# How to use scaled UI content in iOS?

Tags: xcode, user-interface

I would like to create a **zoomed/scaled UI** as in **Screenshot 1** below:

Keep in mind that I am **NOT** using the **Zoomed** option in **iOS Display Settings**.

So, somehow it is possible to make an app look like it is scaled/ zoomed.

Are such apps created with an old version of XCode and that's why their UI looks scaled or it is some sort of a technic?

**Screenshot 1 (taken on iPhone 6s Plus 1920x1080)**

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone 6s Plus - 1920x1080px]

**Screenshot 2 - Normal app**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hi by default the OS will scale your app EITHER because it is an iphone app running on an iPad or because AX is on or it is a very old app where the LaunchImage does tell ios it doesnt really support the screen size.

you cant really say 'hey ios, scale my whole app for me'

that said, you can DRAW 'scaled' by applying a transformation to your root window/view.. dont know if there are issues with scaling the whole hierrachy but it technically works

Answer (score 0):

i just know the bug with facebook sdk its when you call your fb friends list in the app and it scales all the ui after that window xd